# How to get activerecord associations via reflection

Tags: ruby, reflection, activerecord

For normal columns, you can get at them via the `columns` class method. However, associations may be named something quite different if the `foreign_key` option is set in the relationship method. For example, given

```
class Post
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => :message_id # this is a contrived example
end
```

if I did `Post.column_names` I could get at `message_id`, but is there any way to get `comments`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`Model.reflections` gives information about a model's associations. It is a `Hash` keyed on the association name. e.g.

```
Post.reflections.keys # => ["comments"]
```

Here is an example of some of the information it can be used to access:

```
Post.reflections["comments"].table_name # => "comments"
Post.reflections["comments"].macro # => :has_many
Post.reflections["comments"].foreign_key # => "message_id"
```

---

*Note:* this answer has been updated to cover Rails 4.2 based on [MCB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167965/mcb)'s answer and the comments below. In earlier versions of Rails the reflection's `foreign_key` was accessed using `primary_key_name` instead, and the keys for the reflections may be symbols instead of strings depending on how the association was defined e.g. `:comments` instead of `"comments"`.

Comment: FYI guys, reflections just returns a hash, not a HashWithIndifferentAccess. So the keys of the .reflections hash will be either a symbol or a string, depending on what it says in the model definition. This just tripped me up thinking it would be either or.

Comment: As MCB said in his answer, in Rails 4.2, you say `Post.reflections["comments"]`instead

Comment: thanks @AsfandYarQazi - I've updated the answer to incorporate the differences for Rails 4.2+

Comment: your answer help me improve collect info about Rails database: https://gist.github.com/r72cccp/3480f4e13f00d54d4cb87bfd4077c8aa

Answer (score 20):

For future Googlers in Rails 4 the answer would now be:

```
Post.reflections[:comments].foreign_key # => "message_id"
```

Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364743/2167965

EDIT:

`reflections`, as of 4.2, now takes strings instead of symbols which is a fun bug to track down. If you want to keep using symbols you should switch to `reflect_on_association(:assoc_name)`. Also note `reflections` are actually [the public api](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14682) which will keep reporting things like HABTM, even though it's all has many through under the hood. The reflections Rails is actually using are now in `_reflections`

Answer (score -1):

For an ActiveRecord object I use:

```
object._reflections
```

So, I can manipulate the Hash returned. For instance:

```
object._reflections.keys.each do |key|
    object.public_send(key).destroy_all
end
```

The above example delete all the relationships from database.

Comment: It is not advised to use underscored methods on Rails, they may change at any moment without warning, which will cause bugs when upgrading