# List reference columns of a active record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

using Rails 3.2, there is a way to find out if a column is a reference column to other model?

I don't want to rely in "_id" string search in the name.

thanks.

UPDATE:

I need to iterate over all columns and made a special treatment in references columns, something like:

```
result = Hash.new
self.attribute_names.each do |name|
  if self[name]
    result[name] = self[name]

    if name is reference column
       insert xxx_description (from the other model) in hash.
    end
  end
end
```

I will return this hash as json to client.

{name: 'joseph', sector_id: 2, sector_name: 'backend'...}

Where sector_name, is person.sector.name...

thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @onurozgurozkan yes, a bit of context would be good. There's probably a better solution than playing with the columns to any problem i can think of

Comment: Sorry, i just updated my question.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer, but now that i have more context, i'd say that, if possible, using `as_json` or `to_json` with options like `include` would be far more simple, and is the convention. See http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternative method if you don't know the name of the association :

```
Post.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map &:foreign_key 
# => ['author_id','category_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html

```
Post.reflections[:comments].primary_key_name # => "message_id"
```

[How to get activerecord associations via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173333/how-to-get-activerecord-associations-via-reflection)