# Rails 4: undefined method `primary_key_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm receiving the following error using Rails 4.0.0.beta:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `primary_key_name' for #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection
```

I don't get the exception when using Rails 3.2.x.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p194 for both Rails 3.2.13 and Rails 4.0.0.beta.

The problem stems from the following `has_many` statement:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :customers, :through => :relationships, :source => :user,
    :conditions => { :relationships => { :description => "Customer" } } do
      def <<(user)
        proxy_association.owner.relationships.create(:description => "Customer", :user => user)
      end
    end
end
```

I have following supporting classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :relationship
  has_one :store, :through => :relationship
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'd like to know how I can achieve the same `has_many` functionality using a Rails 4-friendly code?

P.S. I'm aware I'm still using old-style syntax, and that the conditions hash now requires a proc or lambda, but these shouldn't causing the `undefined method` exception.

Comment: When are you getting this error? Running tests? The only place I see a reference in the Rails 4 repo for "primary_key_name" is in [ActiveRecord::FixtureSet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L574-L576). Otherwise, maybe it's a gem that is incompatible with Rails 4.

Comment: I'm getting this error trying to populate seeds using the Seedbank gem. However, I have tried just executing a few create statements (console) that involve a store model, and it also fails on that line. I don't think it has anything to do with Seedbank or seeding in general. It's definitely to do with `has_many :customers`. The line number for the error also identifies this line as the culprit. I looked up the method and could only find the reference the ActiveRecord::FixtureSet too. The `ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection. primary_key_name` method has been deprecated since 3.1.0.

Comment: I'm in the process of eliminating gem dependencies for the project one by one... I'm hoping to find one of those is the culprit.

Comment: You might be able to search your gems directory for "primary_key_name" to see if any of them reference it explicitly.

Comment: @Beerlington, I'm happy to award you the accepted answer if you want to post your suggestion as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the culprit, it's the `perfectline/validates_existence` gem which defaults to the deprecated `primary_key_name` instead of `foreign_key` when the `ActiveRecord::VERSION::MINOR >= 1` - go figure! I've submitted a pull request with the fix (https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence/pull/20). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Beerlington.