# shoulda-matcher `belongs_to` is producing this error: undefined method `primary_key_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I have a Rails 4 application with a belongs_to relationship which I am trying to test with shoulda-matcher:

The model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

The test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

Rspec.describe Foo, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to :bar }
end
```

Produces the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `primary_key_name' for #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x007fde9b87e368>
   Did you mean?  primary_key_type
```

If I use the uglier:

```
it { Foo.reflect_on_association(:bar).macro.should  eq(:belongs_to) }
```

The test passes.

I have seen [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360418/rails-4-undefined-method-primary-key-name) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/414), but they refer to a different matcher and blames the `validates_existence` gem which I do not have installed.

I can live with the long-hand syntax, but any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

It looks like my problem was related to gem versions. I changed the versions of shoulda and shoulda-matchers and the relationship matchers now work correctly.

Original gem versions:

```
rails: 4.2.6
shoulda: 2.11.3
shoulda-matchers: 3.1.1
```

Working gem versions:

```
shoulda: 3.5.0
shoulda-matchers: 2.8.0
```

Comment: Would you please post the full backtrace with an exact reference to the line that failed? `ActiveRecord` is open sourced.

Comment: which versions of rails and shoulda have you exactly?, abd please show your schema for the `foos` table

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ It looks like the versions of rails/shoulda/shoulda-matchers were the problem. Unfortunately, I didn't notice how far back the shoulda version was last night.