# Retrieving name of a :through table from an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I have tables that are joined to each other via `has_many :through => join_table`.

I am trying to create a *generic* function (because I have many such triplets, and I want to be able to re-use this function) that needs to take as input 2 table names and be able to get the actual name of the aforementioned `join_table`.

I am thinking something (using tables `users` and `groups`, for example) like:

```
 users.groups.joiner
```

I have been searching around and I haven't found anything yet. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Call the `reflections` method on the Class Model of TableA. Then use the name of TableB to navigate the hash, like in the accepted answer here: ([How to get activerecord associations via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173333/how-to-get-activerecord-associations-via-reflection)).

Maneuver until you get the value of the `:through` reflection for TableA and TableB.